# Error uploading user picuture vai Graph api

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to upload an image from local drive to Graph via the [UploadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
api. Here is my code

```
string filename = "S:\\28-sept\\leo.jpg";
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);   

// GetHttpRequest return HtppRequestMessage with Bearer token set. 
// I confirm graphAccessToken is correctly set                   


 var req =  GetHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Put, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/fe7b8732-ca7b-4cc7-b524-4093fc13dfd3e/photo/$value", logger);
 ByteArrayContent streamContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
 streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
 req.Content = streamContent;
    
 var client = new HttpClient();          
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
 string strResp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code":"**UnknownError**",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date":"2024-01-25T16:42:32",
      "request-id":"{{Some-GUID}}",
      "client-request-id":"{{Some-GUID}}"
    }
  }
}
```

The application permissions are [image].

Any idea what's going on? Do I have to grant `User.ReadWrite.All` Application permissions for this?

Comment: How do you authenticate? With client secret or something else?

Comment: Based on your scenario and description along with the shared code snippet its seems that, you need to grant the `User.ReadWrite.All` application permission for your app to update profile pictures. This is essential for modifying user data through the Graph API

Comment: the authentication is done via a registered app and its client secret . Thanks!